# Limit the number of concurrent users in an IIS web application

Tags: c#, postgresql, iis

I want to limit the concurrent users in my application. Let's say I have 50 users of my application, but I want at one time only 20 users are allowed to access my application (C# frontend and PostGre backend).

One way is to log every user entry in database and check on every login if that exceeds the maximum user limit.

Is there any way in IIS or at windows level or any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS it is possible to set the maximum sessions, perhaps this will work.

In IIS, click your Site, then double click ASP, expand the Session Properties and update the Maximum Sessions field.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but still not working, i set MaxSession filed=2 and when i try with two different browser , then for Ist,second time page loads it works but on third time page css does not loads properly , and some time jquery not loads properly. On second browser it shows "Service Unavailable".